# 100 units of a product in a factory. 5 are defective. We pick three at random. What is the probability that exactly one product is defective?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

For this question, my answer would be and thats how we did it in class (5/100)(95/99)(94/98)

however, my professor sent a correction email saying that we have to multiply that answer by 3. I am confused as to why? Can someone explain?

Comment: Your answer was the probability that if you picked three **in sequence** that very specifically *the first* was defective and then the next two are not.  You missed the possibility that the first and last were not but the *second* is, or the possibility that the first and second were not but the *third* is.

Comment: It can be easier to view this as the [hypergeometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_distribution#:~:text=In%20probability%20theory%20and%20statistics,that%20contains%20exactly%20objects%20with) and using binomial coefficients.  The answer being $\dfrac{\binom{5}{1}\binom{95}{2}}{\binom{100}{3}}$